# Cross processor platform Binary Serialisation

Tags: c#, ios, windows, xamarin.ios

I'm not able to test this (not with my windows machine at the moment)

but can I, using the built in .Net Binary Serialisation methods; serialise/deserialise an object across each platform?

The object is stored in an external library and built for Armv7 and intel.

you see I have built a library for iOS and built the same library for windows (assembly names, versions match across the 2), I need to serialise an object (within the library) between both the systems.

I have searched, but couldn't find any answers (here or the internet)

the members in the object (Name, EmployeeRef, Age etc etc) are all .net types.

I know I can use json or xml but performance is key here and the object can be potentially large.

I have also gave protobuf a try, but this has problems with the iOS Unified API that we are targeting.

Comment: It seems like you have already answered your own question since you know of the existence of JSON/XML serialization as well as other alternatives such as protobuf. Each language/runtime has it's own way of doing things, so unfortunately you are out of luck.

Comment: Are you referring to the platform doing things its own way or, referring to the runtime?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/bond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are lots of solutions to this type of problem, the one you mentioned which is Protocol Buffers from Google. You say this does not work well with the iOS api you are using.

How about Thrift?

https://thrift.apache.org/

http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftUsageObjectiveC

That was invented by facebook for fast cross language serialization.

Something along those lines is going to be your best bet.

EDIT: As per SLaks comment the Bond library is another library that was written by Microsoft and recently open sourced which does the same kind of thing. (Not sure how good iOS support is going to be though)

http://github.com/Microsoft/bond

Comment: I have used it in .NET to serialize with Python and Java services without any issue. Cant speak about iOS but it seems pretty solid there too just from a few Google searches.

Comment: Well the language here is .Net (but across Arm & Intel) we are using Xamarin.iOS which utilises Mono for its .Net implementation, so type support i believe won't be a problem, I thinks its more about the binary output from the different processors. Still I'm going to take a look to see if can help in any way.

Comment: I see what you are saying.. your using .NET on both sides... Hopefully it will help generate a common object :)